# Errors were encountered while processing: libxau-dev:amd64

Tags: package-management, java, openjdk

I have removed Java version 1.8 and now want to install version 1.7. All the time I am getting `error(1) with libxau-dev file` so I am trying to install it and getting message below:

```
my@server:~$ sudo apt-get install libxau-dev
sudo: unable to resolve host server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxau-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  icc-profiles-free java-wrappers libapache-pom-java
  libatinject-jsr330-api-java libavalon-framework-java libbcprov-java
  libbsf-java libcofoja-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-io-java
  libcommons-logging-java libcommons-math-java libcommons-net1-java
  libcommons-parent-java libguava-java libhamcrest-java libhdf5-8
  libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java libjama-java libjargs-java
  libjaxp1.3-java libjcommon-java libjfreechart-java libjgraph-java
  libjgrapht0.8-java libjhdf5-java libjhdf5-jni libjide-oss-java
  libjlibeps-java libjline-java libjsr305-java liblog4j1.2-java liboro-java
  librhino-java libsam-java libsaxon-java libswing-layout-java libx11-doc
  libxalan2-java libxdmcp-dev libxerces2-java libxml-commons-external-java
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxmlgraphics-commons-java
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 11.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libxau-dev amd64 1:1.0.8-1 [11.1 kB]
Fetched 11.1 kB in 9s (1,137 B/s)                                              
dpkg: error processing package libxau-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxau-dev:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
my@server:~$
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Start `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get purge libxau-dev; sudo apt-get install libxau-dev`

Comment: I tried upgrade, clean, purge, remove commands and I still gets this msg: dpkg: error processing package libxau-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxau-dev:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Use the main server via `sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/in/http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update` and try it again: `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get purge libxau-dev; sudo apt-get install libxau-dev`

Comment: Sorry Sir, I still got the msg -->                                                                                          my@server:~$ sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/in/http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo: unable to resolve host server
my@server:~$

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: When I typed this command --> my@server>sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/in/http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update ->Reading package lists...Done                                                  
W: Failed to fetch http://.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Please mention what command to be typed , I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: output of command >sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/in/http:\/\//' is --> sudo:unable to resolve host server

Comment: Crap, I forgot a dot... Start this: `sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/\./http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: And, new results?

Comment: You can install `libxau-dev:amd64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the comments by using the mainserver via

```
sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/in\./http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge libxau-dev
sudo apt-get install libxau-dev
```